Problemas con fechas en PowerBI
Estoy trabajando en Power BI para graficar la ubicación de varios árboles en un campo, y quiero realizar un seguimiento del estado de cada árbol a lo largo del tiempo. Tengo una tabla de hechos con entradas que registran diferentes datos sobre estos árboles en diferentes fechas. El formato de las fechas en mi conjunto de datos es dd/mm/aaaa.
Quiero visualizar únicamente los datos más recientes para cada árbol, es decir, los datos correspondientes a la última fecha registrada. También tengo filtros aplicados (como el estado de los árboles) y solo quiero que se muestren los datos más recientes para que los filtros sean significativos.
Usé DAX para encontrar la última fecha en la tabla con esta fórmula:
UltimaFecha = FORMAT(MAX('Tabla 1'[Fecha]), "dd/mm/yyyy")

Me aseguré que la UltimaFecha sea realmente formato fecha (por las dudas):
FechaComoFecha = DATEVALUE('Tabla 1'[UltimaFecha])

Luego, creé una columna para marcar las filas con la última fecha
FechaMax = IF('Tabla 1'[Fecha] >= 'Tabla 1'[FechaComoFecha], 1, 0)

Mi idea es usar un filtro en la página de Power BI para mostrar solo las entradas donde FechaMax sea igual a 1, de modo que solo se vean los datos más recientes de cada árbol.
Aunque este método parece me parecia lógico, no estoy seguro de que sea la forma más eficiente o correcta de hacerlo. Además, tengo problemas para hacer que funcione correctamente y solo muestre las filas más recientes.
¿Hay una mejor manera de hacer esto? ¿Que error tengo? Cualquier consejo o alternativa les agradezco mucho.
Gracias por su tiempo!!!

Ya pude solucionarlo. Al final, el enfoque estaba bien, pero Power BI no reconocía la fecha como tal, sino como texto. Lo arreglé yendo al menú de arriba y cambiando el tipo de dato (después de ajustar algunas fórmulas), y ahora lo toma correctamente.
